# How to read a large DBF File using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dbf

I have a large DBF File which i need parse and convert into a pandas dataframe.
I am using dbfread module to read the file and convert it into a iterator, reading the iterator in chunks and each chunk is converted into a dataframe.i need to speed up the process so that the chunking happens in multi processing. Below is the code that is being used

```
dbase = DBF(vdf,ignore_missing_memofile = True)
Record_length = dbase.header.numrecords
print(Record_length)
Processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
chunk_size = Record_length//Processes
def process_chunk(start,end):
    records = []
    for i,record in enumerate(dbase):
        if i>=start and i<end:
            records.append(record)
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)
    print(f"{start},{end} records are processed")
    return df
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
args=[(i*chunk_size,(i+1)*chunk_size) for i in range(Processes)]
results  = pool.starmap(process_chunk, args)
# results = [pool.apply_async(process_chunk, arg) for arg in args]
final_df = pd.concat(results)
```

However it seems like multiprocessing is not working as expected ,because the code takes more time  to execute than it takes to sequentially process each chunk.
So how to efficiently read a dbf file in chunks and convert it into a pandas dataframe using multi processing?

Edit 1- after implementing suggestions from ethan,now the code looks like

```
dbase = dbf.Table(vdf)
Processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2
chunk_size = len(dbase)//Processes
def process_chunk(start,end):records = []
    dbase.open()
    for record in dbase[start:end]:
    records.append(tuple(record))
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)
    # print(f"from {start} to {end} records are processed")
    dbase.close()
    return df

args=[(i*chunk_size,(i+1)*chunk_size) for i in range(Processes)]
#results = pool.starmap(process_chunk, args)
results = [pool.apply_async(process_chunk, arg) for arg in args]
# output = [r.get() for r in results]
```

I think the table should be opened and closed in the process_chunk function.
Even after using dbf module. Still seeing that it is as same as sequential processing. The File is of 1gb and i takes 5 minutes in original code and it takes 4.7 minutes in the edited code.
Also when I convert it to data frame, headers are not being converted to data frame headers.

Answer (score 1):

Your `process_chunk` function is iterating/reading the entire dbf file each time -- so on an eight-core machine you read the entire file eight times.  Instead of using `enumerate`, you need to directly select just the records in each chunk.

I'm not familiar with `dbfread`, but an example using my own [`dbf` library](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/) would look something like:

```
import dbf

dbase = dbf.Table(vdf, ignore_memos=True)
Processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
chunk_size = len(dbase)/Processes

def process_chunk(start, end):
    records = []
    for rec in dbase[start:end]:         # instead of `enumerate`
        records.append(tuple(rec))       # may work without the `tuple`
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)
    return df
```

---

The table can be opened once before processing, and closed once after all the processing is done (i.e. it doesn't have to be done repeatedly in the `process_chunk()` function).

You can try using the record directly, instead of casting it to tuple:

```
    records.append(record)
```

That may help with the headers.

The biggest slow-down with processing disk files is disk access -- how long does it take to actually read in all that data?

For example:

```
# base time to read data
import time, dbf
start = time.time()
data = open(vdf).read()
end = time.time()
print('read data: %s' % (end-start))

# time to read and convert data from dbf to python (not pandas)
start = time.time()
dbase = dbf.Table(vdf)
with dbase:
    for rec in dbase:
        pass
end = time.time()
print('read and convert data: %s' % (end-start))
```

The 'read data' number is the fastest it can be done, and the 'read and convert' is the fastest it can be done using `dbf` (neither of which you'll achieve because of the extra processing needed).

Comment: I have just updated the question after implementing your suggestion..